# Is there a way to get function output in decorators?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def decorator(func):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs, func)

        result = func(*args, **kwargs) # function result

        print("Result value is {}".format(result))
    
    return _

@decorator
def function(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

print(function(2, 2))
```

In decorator, i'm trying to get the result value, but in order to do it, i need to call the function twice. Is there a way to get the result value in decorator immediately, without calling the function twice? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with what you have there? Aside from a missing `return` it looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you are calling the function twice. Do you mean you call it in the decorator as well as here `print(function2, 2))`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: The remove the outer call to `print()` and let the decorator do it (or vice-versa).